# Accessing attribute from another class from another module

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have three module:

The code for main.py looks like:

```
#Instanciate 
P=Person("Alex", "Something")
F=Friend("Arthur", "Whatever")

#call a function
P.to_print()
```

The code for persons.py looks like:

```
from friends import Friend
class Person(Friend):

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def to_print(self):
        print(self.firstname)
        print(Friend.first)
```

The code for friends.py looks like:

```
class Friend:

    def __init__(self, first, last):

        self.first=first
        self.last=last
```

My Question: How can I use the the variable "first" from class "Friend" (module friends.py) in class "Person" (module persons.py). Would be great if anyone can help me. I sure its totally easy, but I am new to OOP.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`first` is an instance variable, not a class variable, so you can't access it via the class name `Friend`; you need an actual instance of `Friend`.

Since every instance of `Person` is a `Friend`, you can just do `self.first`.  However, this value will be empty because your `Person` constructor doesn't call your `Friend` constructor!  To fix this, add a line like:

```
class Person(Friend):

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        Friend.__init__(self, firstname, lastname)
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
```

or:

```
class Person(Friend):

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        super().__init__(firstname, lastname)
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
```

But I don't think this actually does what you're after, because presumably the idea isn't that each person is its own `Friend`.  Instead of having the class `Person` be a subclass of `Friend` I think you want a `Person` instance to be able to have another specific `Person` as its `friend`:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, friend = None):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.friend = friend

    def to_print(self):
        print(self.firstname)
        if self.friend:
            print(self.friend.firstname)

arthur = Person("Arthur", "Whatever")
alex = Person("Alex", "Something", arthur)
alex.to_print()
```